# OpenCV Manager (not found in google play) + hard to install in Oreo

Tags: android, opencv, google-play

I have an app that uses the opencv library. So far, when my app arrives, for the first time, a certain activity asks for the installation of opencv, with the following code...

```
askInstallOpenCV.setPositiveButton(R.string.googleplay, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        AppContext.startActivity(
            new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opencv.engine")
            )
        );
    }
});
```

Since a month ago google play has been reporting OpenCV as not found. My first reaction was to give the possibility of installing from another source but with oreo this became more difficult.
Is there a reason for not found in google play?

Edit:

- If I go from PC to link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opencv.engine OpenCV appears
- If I look for opencv manager in google play with the search option, opencv does not appear
- From cellphone, for some users the opencv is found and can be installed, for others it is not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is ask the user to follow the link you gave,  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opencv.engine, on their device. This should open the Play store at that particular app. If it is not compatible with their device, then you should get a message saying app not compatible.

If the link doesn't follow properly it might be they don't have Google Play installed properly or up to date.

If you get a mesage saying app not compatible I can't see any particular reason why this would be. Try contacting Play Console support, who can be contacted by the help menu, which is behind the "?" (question mark) icon.

*Here ends the general device to anyone. To this specific questioner (and no-one else) - if you find a specific device not compatible and Play console support can't help feel free to ask them to escalate to me (Nick Fortescue). But only do this if you have a specific gmail account and device that doesn't work.*

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you fot your atention. The playstore says that the application is not found. It does not say anything about compatibility and from what I can perceive by my users it is not relevant which version of the OS nor the processor. Even the language is not relevant either. I still can not get a response from google forums because I am very limited on internet connection for 2 or 3 days. The strange thing is that for some users neither in the PC and with the link OpenCV appears.

Comment: Is it possible OpenCV Manager has been removed from Google Play?

Comment: It does indeed look like it has been unpublished by the developer. You would have to ask opencv.org why. In the meantime, you might be better compiling the OpenCV library into your app instead.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. For some gmail accounts the opencv manager is available, but some other gmail accounts it is not available. Very strange.

Comment: The OpenCV app is unpublished which means it is available for any account which had historically installed it, but not for any account which hadn't.

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV manager has been removed from the play store. I found this link to support the assertion (https://answers.opencv.org/question/199341/opencv-manager-app-not-on-playstore/). Their documentation seems to be well out of date, still strongly recommending that you use the OpenCV manager instead of static linking.

> Yes the app has been removed.

> As time shows, the idea of redistributing libraries for Android via separate app seems to be bad. The platform and the library changes so compatibility preserving becomes too difficult and time consuming.

> We suggest using static linking with OpenCV where possible. OpenCV Manager apk is still available in our SDK for Android on SourceForge. For Java users, I believe it is possible to build custom OpenCV SDK for Android configuration with reduced set of modules by providing BUILD_LIST cmake option and utilizing build_sdk script.